# Tasks (parent) and TaskInstances (child): choose 1 image out of 6 with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on compiling a MySQL query with the accompanying HTML output for a display page, but was hoping to get some direction. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Background:**
A TaskInstance is the child while both Tasks and Students are the parents. The TaskInstance table will be ever-growing each time a student signs up for a task, yet the Tasks table have a finite amount, e.g. 20. Each task sits in the Tasks table and has some generic qualities. A user can sign up for a task, but then unique qualities can be assigned to the task using the TaskInstance table. TaskInstance variables include:

- TkInstanceInfoA, TkInstanceInfoB, TkInstanceInfoC, TkInstanceInfoD allow for various descriptions, etc.
- TkInstanceSide indicates whether the task is done on the right side, left side or if there is no side (L, R or null)
- fkTkID tells us which Task is the parent of the TaskInstance
- fkStID tells us which Student is the parent of the TaskInstance

**Database:**

```
Students
1.) StID
2.) StNameFirst
3.) StNameLast
4.) StGender
5.) StPasscode
6.) fkProID

Tasks
1.) TkID
2.) TkSide (the task by nature has a side?: Y or N) 
3.) TkImgML
4.) TkImgMR 
5.) TkImgMC 
6.) TkImgFL 
7.) TkImgFR
8.) TkImgFC
9.) TkTitleSci
10.) TkTitleCom
11.) TkDesc

TaskInstance
1.) TkInstID
2.) TkInstSide (which side is the task?: L, R or null)
3.) TkInstInfoA
4.) TkInstInfoB
5.) TkInstInfoC
6.) TkInstInfoD
7.) TkInstCustomTitleSci
8.) TkInstCustomTitleCom
9.) TkInstCustomDesc
10.) TkInstOrder
11.) fkTkID
12.) fkStID
```

**MySQL:**

*Update: 4/16/2013 12:03 pm EST:* I had the SELECT AND SELECT CASE reversed and was missing the comma. Now corrected, but still breaking:

```
$CurrentStID = 1; // known previously
$CurrentStGender = M; // known previously

SELECT *, 
   CASE StGender
       WHEN 'M' THEN
           CASE IFNULL(TkInstSide, 'C')
                WHEN 'L' THEN TkImgML
                WHEN 'R' THEN TkImgMR
                ELSE TkImgMC
           END
       WHEN 'F' THEN
           CASE IFNULL(TkInstSide, 'C')
                WHEN 'L' THEN TkImgFL
                WHEN 'R' THEN TkImgFR
                ELSE TkImgFC
           END
   END TkImgCase,
   CASE StTitlePref
       WHEN 'Common' THEN
           CASE WHEN TkInstCustomTitleCom IS NULL 
                THEN TkTitleCom 
                ELSE TkInstCustomTitleCom
           END
       WHEN 'Scientific' THEN
           CASE WHEN TkInstCustomTitleSci IS NULL 
                THEN TkTitleSci 
                ELSE TkInstCustomTitleSci
           END
   END TkTitleCase
FROM TaskInstance 
LEFT JOIN Tasks ON fkTkID = TkID 
LEFT JOIN Students ON fkStID = StID
WHERE fkStID = $CurrentStID 
ORDER BY TkInstOrder
```

**Print:**

**1.) Check for custom Title and Description otherwise use standard:**

*Update: 4/16/2013 11:52 am EST:* I've been getting hung up on the custom titles. Should my adjustment work? It seems to be failing.

```
if ($row['StTitlePref'] == "Common") && (strlen(trim($row['TkInstCustomTitleCom'])) > 0) { $TkTitle = $row['TkInstCustomTitleCom'] } // will be default or custom
else if ($row['StTitlePref'] == "Scientific") && (strlen(trim($row['TkInstCustomTitleSci']) > 0) { $TkTitle = $row['TkInstCustomTitleSci'] } // will be default or custom
```

**2.) Select 1 image out of the six:**

Is it good to use MySQL to use gender to eliminate 3 of 6 images, and then later use PHP if/then to select 1 of remaining 3 images?

> If Student’s Gender (StGender) is male, and the Task has a side (TkSide), then show the correct image: if L-side (TkInstanceSide), show L male image (TkImgML); if R-side (TkInstanceSide), show R male image (TkImgMR). If Student’s Gender (StGender) is male, and the Task does not have a side (TkSide) [also TkInstanceSide is null], show center male image (TkImgMC).
>
> If Student’s Gender (StGender) is female, and the Task has a side (TkSide), then show the correct image: if L-side (TkInstanceSide), show L female image (TkImgFL); if R-side (TkInstanceSide), show R female image (TkImgFR). If Student’s Gender (StGender) is female, and the Task does not have a side (TkSide) [also TkInstanceSide is null], show center female image (TkImgFC).

**3.) Display Additional info related to this Instance:**

Display these 4 variables: TkInstanceInfoA, TkInstanceInfoB, TkInstanceInfoC, TkInstanceInfoD.

**So, eventually something like this:**

```
echo ‘<p>’ . $TkTitleCom . ‘<br>’;  // show either standard title or custom title
echo $TkDesc . ‘<br>’; // show either standard description or custom description
echo $TkInstanceInfoA . ‘<br>’;
echo $TkInstanceInfoB . ‘<br>’;
echo $TkInstanceInfoC . ‘<br>’;
echo $TkInstanceInfoD . ‘<br>’;
echo $CorrectImg  . ‘</p>’;  // show either TkImgML, TkImgMR, TkImgMC, TkImgFL, TkImgFR or TkImgFC
```

***4/18/2013: Follow-up question (similar)***

Dear Barmar: Thank you very much for your help. I have a follow-up question if you have a moment. I have a display page where I am just trying to pull from the Tasks table (and not also from the TaskInstance table like before).

I know the $CurrentStGender and $CurrentStTitlePref from a previous query. I still want to use the CASE statments to choose the correct image (1 of 6) and the correct title preference. I am having a tough time trying to figure how to feed my two known variables to the SQL. Can you help?

```
// echo $CurrentStGender . ', ' . $CurrentStTitlePref;

if ($result = $mysqli->query("
SELECT *, 
   CASE CurrentStGender
       WHEN 'M' THEN
           CASE WHEN TkSide == 'Y' THEN TkImgML /* if task can be done on a side, show just the L-side
                ELSE TkImgMC
           END
       WHEN 'F' THEN
           CASE WHEN TkSide == 'Y' THEN TkImgFL /* if task can be done on a side, show just the L-side
                ELSE TkImgFC
           END
   END TkImgCase,
   CASE StTitlePref
       WHEN 'Common' THEN TkTitleCom 
           END
       WHEN 'Scientific' THEN TkTitleSci 
           END
   END TkTitleCase
FROM Tasks
```

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: No, I am not a student. This is a project I am working which, when completed, is meant to help students.

Comment: ok, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Can you get me started with the MySQL code that will line up the data correctly? I gave a try at it, but don't know about my INNER JOIN.

Comment: Similarly, I was looking to get started on the IF/THEN/ELSE PHP statements specifically to get that correct image (1 of 6) to show. I am unsure if I process this through weeding it on in the SQL or weeding it out through IF/THEN statements.

Comment: No reason not to do the IF/THEN/ELSE stuff in MySQL as well.

Comment: @webdude77: custom title: write `elseif` instead of `else if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the image based on gender and side in SQL:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE StGender
           WHEN 'M' THEN
               CASE IFNULL(TkSide, 'C')
                    WHEN 'L' THEN TkImgML
                    WHEN 'R' THEN TkImgMR
                    ELSE TkImgMC
               END
           WHEN 'F' THEN
               CASE IFNULL(TkSide, 'C')
                    WHEN 'L' THEN TkImgFL
                    WHEN 'R' THEN TkImgFR
                    ELSE TkImgFC
               END
       END TkImg
FROM TaskInstance 
LEFT JOIN Tasks ON fkTkID = TkID 
LEFT JOIN Students ON fkStID = StID
WHERE fkStID = $CurrentStID 
ORDER BY TkInstOrder
```

Answer to followup:

There are two ways you could do this. One is to keep the current two-level CASE structure, but replace the column name with a literal that you fill in with the PHP variable (any expression is allowed in a CASE statement, so a literal is just as good as a column name):

```
CASE '$CurrentStGender'
   WHEN 'M' THEN ...
   WHEN 'F' THEN ...
END TkImgCase,
CASE '$CurrentStTitlePref'
    WHEN 'Common' THEN TkTitleCom 
        END
    WHEN 'Scientific' THEN TkTitleSci 
        END
END TkTitleCase
```

Another takes advantage of the fact that your columns follow naming conventions, so you can interpolate directly into the column names:

```
$titleAbbrev = substr($CurrentStTitlePref, 0, 3);
if ($result = $mysqli->query("
  SELECT *,     
     CASE WHEN TkSide == 'Y' THEN TkImg{$CurrentStGender}L
          ELSE TkImg{$CurrentStGender}C
     END TkImgCase,
     TkTitle{$titleAbbrev} TkTitleCase
  FROM Tasks");
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Would I embed this into my main SQL statement? Or, would this be a separate statement?

`SELECT * FROM TaskInstance LEFT JOIN Tasks ON fkTkID = TkID WHERE fkStID = $CurrentStID ORDER BY TaskInstance.TkInstOrder`

Comment: This is intended to be part of the main SQL statement, the `...` represents the rest of the statement that you already have.

Comment: Or just try it in your application. If it works, it works. If it doesn't, update the question with what you tried.

Comment: Sorry, I have now updated the original question. Yes, I have been trying in my application throughout. Above, in the original question, I have indicated my update with italics. So, I was wondering, is the SELECT CASE added to the end of my SQL statement? I seem to be getting an error with the single quoted M's. I tried double quotes and it also failed.

Comment: It gets merged into the original SQL statement. See my updated answer. You may need to use `IFNULL()` in the `CASE` expressions to deal with TaskInstances that have no  parent Task or Student.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. My input pages will be created such that TaskInstances cannot be created without a parent Task or Student. Still, it might be nice to have this added protection. How would I add the IFNULL() statement into the MySQL expression? Also, might you have some ideas for adjusting my updated IF/ELSE IF statements above in my original question called: "Print: 1.) Check for custom Title and Description otherwise use standard"?

Comment: I assumed they couldn't have parent Student or Task because you used a LEFT JOIN -- this is only necessary when you want to select rows that have no match in the joining table. I've added a null check for the side, to treat it as Center. I don't know how you want to default gender, but you can do it similarly.

Comment: I don't understand your custom title stuff -- you have described what to do when custom titles are set, but not when they're not. But why don't you give a try of turning your logic into CASE statements like mine -- learn by doing.

Comment: I tried performing the logic for a new CASE statement. I am not sure how sound my null and not nulls are, but it seems to work in MySQL. Does it seem to make sense to you? For some reaseon, when I output in PHP, I am not getting a value. So close! Ideas? Thanks for the help and coaching.
`echo 'TkTitle: ' . $row['$TkTitleCase'] . '<br>';`

Comment: You can't test for null that way. You have to write `CASE WHEN TkInstCustomTitleCom IS NULL THEN TkTitleCom ELSE TkInstCustomTitleCom`, `IF(TkInstCustomTitleCom IS NULL, TkTitleCom, TkInstCustomTitleCom)`, or simply `IFNULL(TkInstCustomTitleCom, TkTitleCom)`

Comment: I tried to use the longhand version above (updated in my original MySQL call). Still, something is not quite right. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have an extra word between `CASE` and `WHEN`.

Comment: Thank you. I've removed and changed the original question above. This, as before, results in a successful query when using MySQL SQL Panel. In the Panel, I get a correct value for the first CASE (TkImgCase) and for the second CASE (TkTitleCase). When I output in PHP, I get good data for the first CASE (TkImgCase), but not for second CASE (TkTitleCase). TkTitleCase is not passing any data. I am stumped! In the PHP, both are appearing within a call like:  
`while($row = $result->fetch_array())`
and are printed with a:
`echo '<strong>' . $row['$TkTitleCase'] . '</strong><br>';`

Comment: When you don't set a custom title, is `TkInstCustomTitleCom` set to NULL or to the empty string? `IS NULL` only checks for NULL.

Comment: I thought you solved it! In fact, the database variable did not have the attribute of being null, so it was just an empty string. My mistake! I just changed TkInstCustomTitleCom and TkInstCustomTitleSci to be nullable, and then updated the 1 record that I have been playing with to the value of null. I thought this would solve it, but it has not.

Comment: Can you post some sample data to sqlfiddle.com so I can look at it?

Comment: Silly mistake on my end. I had an extra dollar sign when I printed the variable from my array (I had $row['$ExTitleCase']): It is fixed and works!

`while($row = $result->fetch_array())
  {
  echo '<strong>' . $row['ExTitleCase'] . '</strong><br>';
  }`

Comment: Barmar: Thank you very much for your help! These CASE statements in SQL are a great help! Do you think the way I call the array in my comment above is the best and safest way to do it? You seem to have good approaches and I was curious as to how you call your arrays.

Comment: I have a follow-up question that is a stripped down version of my question above. Basically, I have a need to do a query without the INNER JOIN, and simply feed two known variables into the SQL query. Can you see my post in the original question (at the bottom).

Comment: Sorry, I had accepted the answer, and then unaccepted thinking that might bring your attention back to the question. I understand now that this is not the right way to do things. I will ask a new question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Print**

```
if (strlen(trim($TkInstCustomTitleCom)) > 0) $tkTitleCom = $tkInstCustomTitleCom;
echo $tkTitleCom; // will be default or custom
```

**(2) Print**

Try this instead of `if ... else`; the expression inside the (brackets) is called a `ternary operator`, the expression in line 2 is a `variable variable`:

```
$image = "TkImg" . $StGender . ($TkSide=='Y'?$TkInstanceSide:'C');
$imagename = $$image; // now $imagename contains the content of e.g. $TkImgMC
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/abpxbU

Comment: I've been getting hung up on the custom titles. Should my adjustment in the original question work? It seems to be failing.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL**

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM TaskInstance
LEFT JOIN Tasks ON fkTkID = TkID
WHERE fkStID = :stID
ORDER BY TkInstOrder 
SQL;
```

same but different:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TaskInstance LEFT JOIN Tasks ON fkTkID = TkID WHERE fkStID = :stID ORDER BY TkInstOrder";
```

`:stID` is a parameter, the query a parameterized query. It's safe against SQL-injection. You'd be using PDO functions instead of mysql_* (which is deprecated).

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: This is helpful. I guess I am not familiar with the formatting of <<<SQL and :stID. Is my statement equivalent and acceptable?

`SELECT * FROM TaskInstance LEFT JOIN Tasks ON fkTkID = TkID WHERE fkStID = $CurrentStID ORDER BY TaskInstance.TkInstOrder`